# Cannot add lines to a chart using Vaadin SOCharts

Tags: javascript, java, charts, vaadin, echarts

I've tried almost everything to solve it by myself but i cannot find a way to create a line with a start position and an end position and add it to a chart. From the documentation that I found on [HERE](https://storedobject.com/api/com/storedobject/chart/Line.html) I coded the snippet below. The xValues and yValues are some random values that I generated for a LineChart but I also tried with some custom numeric values.

Any help would be really appreciated ❤️.

```java
// Add a custom line on the chart
Line line = new Line(new Shape.Point(xValues.get(99900), yValues.get(99900)), new Shape.Point(xValues.get(99990), yValues.get(99990)));
line.setName("Linea importantissima");
line.getStyle(true).setFillColor(new Color("red"));
line.getStyle(true).setLineWidth(10);

soChart.add(... , line);
```

Comment: I dont know anything about Vaadin but in echarts its neccessary to set the size of the underlying div. From [SO Charts](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/so-charts) sample code I can see a similar procedure: `soChart.setSize("800px", "500px");`. Are you setting the size? Are you able to get any visual output other than a line?

Comment: I always used setSizeFull() to make the chart responsive but as you suggested I also tried to set a fixed sizing and this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/ZF7fMub

Comment: A gist containing the source is here: https://gist.github.com/MyHouseIsBig/36d3ef9e4d039a64493a33d905f942fa

Comment: Is the given image an improvement? How do you want it to look?

Comment: There should be a big red line that goes from 99900 to 99990

Comment: You are also setting the yValues to 99900 and 99990. Is this intentional?

Comment: I'm setting the values to a certain index in the xValues or yValues array. For example xValues.get(99900) is equal to 99900 but yValues.get(99900)) is equal to something between 0.1 and 0.9

Comment: mhh.. and you are sure that the syntax should work like that? Maybe its only plotting two points which are not shown on the large scale. Try plotting only a few points to reduce complexity. How would you add multiple additional lines?